# How to write a pickup service function in java

Tags: java, mongodb, rabbitmq

I am using RabbitMQ and MongoDB. I need to write a service function in java to store the data in MongoDB when RabbitMQ triggers a message from Queue.

The architecture will be like

[image]

Do RabbitMQ have the ability to pass an XML file from Queue to Pickup Service? Please help. I am new to all these technologies.

Answer (score 1):

Your `PickupService` will have to subscrible to relevant topic of RMQ to receive messages from queue. Messages are pushed to subscribers in async way.
RMQ cannot send file, but can send content of file as plain text - xml in your example.

As you have stated that you are "new" to this, if you are familiar with Swing applications, then message broadcasting is similar to the action listeners in Swing. You cant register multiple `actionListener`s to a button click event and all the listeners will be notified when button is clicked.

The same is here, you can have multiple subscribers (actionListeners) to a topic (button) and they will get the message (button click event) when producer will send it to the queue (user clicks the button)